# How can we interpret negative adjusted rand index?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, pattern-recognition

Adjusted rand index (ARI) is a popular measure to compare two clusters. Unfortunately, I usually get negative ARI after performing clustering analysis and comparing them. How can I interpret these negative ARIs to describe the differences of those clusters? And then if the negative ARIs are meaningless, any suggestion about an appropriate measure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They aren't "meaningless" at all.

Negative ARI says that the agreement is less than what is expected from a random result. This means the results are 'orthogonal' or 'complementary' to some extend.

But this shouldn't happen often, unless you deliberately look for alternative clusterings. Maybe there is an implementation error?

Comment: Thanks. I have checked the codes and it works now after making some corrections. I have found that it is possible to get negative ARIs but these papers did not explain under which circumstances they can be obtained. So what do you mean that the clustering results are 'orthogonal'?

Comment: They are more different than random, I.e. there is a *pattern* to the differences. Which is more likely to arise from implementation errors than by chance, unless you search for that.